# Поменять строки в матрице

Tags: c++, c++11

Дана матрица следующего вида `std::array<std::array<value_type, M>, N> matrix;`. Как поменять в ней `i` и `j` строки? Этот код не хочет менять содержимое матриц, хоть и меняет содержимое `tmp_row`:

```
auto tmp_row = matrix[i];
std::swap(tmp_row, matrix[j]);
std::swap(tmp_row, matrix[i]);
```

Comment: Попробуйте обменивать значения напрямую: `std::swap(matrix[i], matrix[j]);`.

Comment: В цикле меняйте, просто swap не поменяет

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk, что именно надо поместить в цикл? Работает он с двумя конкретными строками. Сами же перемещаемые строки имеют тип `std::array`, то есть вопрошающий вызывает `std::swap(std::array<value_type, M>&, std::array<value_type, M>&);` — соответствующая перегрузка обменивает местами *все* элементы обрабатываемой пары строк.

Comment: Да, я был невнимателен, задача поменять только 2 строки. Вы правы.